# FluentValidation ModelState.IsValid always true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Ok my problem is the modelvalidator from fluentValidation is not working in my project, and ModelState.IsValid is always true no matter the state of the validation, im using asp.net mvc 4, .net 4.5, thx in advance.

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
    }
```

LoginViewModel

```
using FluentValidation.Attributes;

namespace ViewModel.Cuentas
{

 [Validator(typeof(LoginViewModel))]
 public class LoginViewModel
 {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }
}
```

LoginViewModelValidator

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Results;
namespace ViewModel.Cuentas.Validadores
{
    public class LoginViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginViewModelValidator()
        {
        RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El Campo Usuario es Necesario");
        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El Campo Usuario es Necesario");
        }
   }
}
```

and my account controller

> ```
>    [HttpPost]
>     [AllowAnonymous]
>     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>     public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
>     {
>         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             return View();
>         }
>         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(viewModel.UserName, false);
>         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && returnUrl != "/")
>         {
>             return Redirect(returnUrl);
>         }
>         return RedirectToAction("Enviar", "Cartas");
>     }
> ```

Comment: ***Why did you edit your question with correct answer?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Validator` attribute appears to have the wrong type. You have:

```
[Validator(typeof(LoginViewModel))]
public class LoginViewModel
```

The type argument should be your validator class - `LoginViewModelValidator`. So it would be like this:

```
[Validator(typeof(LoginViewModelValidator))]
public class LoginViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to accepted answer: 
If user using **Aspnet** **Core** framework need to be registered as service in Statrup.cs ( under 'ConfigureServices' method)

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<LoginViewModel>, LoginViewModelValidator>();
```

> [Validator(typeof(LoginViewModelValidator))] filter may not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to register your validators.

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<LoginViewModel>, LoginViewModelValidator>();
```

or

```
.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
```