# Fluent validation does not execute when filed is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I've got a problem using using fluent validation and to be honest i don't quite understand whats going on.

I've got a model consisting of

```
public class Model
{
    public int A { get; set;}
    public int B  { get; set;}
    public string C {get; set;}
}

public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.A).InclusiveBetween(1,10).WithMessage("something");

        RuleFor(model => model.B).NotEmpty().WithMessage("test message").InclusiveBetween(1,5).WithMessage("something2");

        // Few other rules 
    }
}
```

The problem is if I will leave form filed blank which will be bound (after submit) to property A or B in Model all i get is validation error '"A" must not be empty' or in case of B "test messsage". I don't get any errors and messages for other properties in the model despite theirs incorrect values (checked ModelState) in debugger. If A and B are filled with incorrect values but not blank everything works fine. Am i not setting some kind of validator flag or something cuz frankly i have i have no idea what's going on because after my experiment with giving .NotEmpty() validator for property B i found out that custom this validator is after all source of message (in case of a it must be some kind of default message).

Action Code (which i think does not matter because ModelState is set after model binding (I've been checking it at the beginning of action invocation).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("done") //Ok there is some BL call logic here but it does not affect Model/Request state
}
return View("");

}
```

EDIT: My guess is that blank filed in form gets posted as empty string. In model I've got an non nullable int -> which cannot be easily converted into correct value for int. What i don't understand is why validation logic executes only partially. I am sure that validator actually gets executed because using validator NotEmpty() with custom validation message actually changes message for the field. What i do not understand why it looks like only this one validator gets executed.

My first guess was that those are ModelBinding Errors rather then validation errors. But then again Validator is capable of changing this message -> so he executes after all. But why all other Validators in rules except this one get ignored?

EDIT:

**Ok let's do a little tweak:**

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.A).InclusiveBetween(1,10).WithMessage("something");

        RuleFor(model => model.B).NotEmpty().WithMessage("test message").InclusiveBetween(1,5).WithMessage("something2");

        RuleFor(model => model.C).Must(x => x.Length > 10).WithMessage("to short");
    }
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

Form:

- A = 11,
- B = 6
- C = "text"

**Result: Returned Messages/Errors:**

- "something"
- "something2"
- "to short"

**Scenario 2:**

Form

- A = "" // THE FORM FIELD LEFT BLANK
- B = "" // THE FORM FIELD LEFT BLANK
- C = "text"

**Result: Returned Messages/Errors:**

- "'A' must be not empty"
- "test message"

// NO MESSAGE FOR C - ONLY THOSE 2 YET THERE SHOULD BE MESSAGE FOR C

Comment: Where does the ModelState come in?  I can't see anything checking the model state.  Does this help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367799/fluentvalidation-modelstate-isvalid-always-true ?

Comment: That's good question. I am using FluentValidation with Unity IoC.

I am talking about ModelState from controller Action. But there is no logic there. What i am sure of is that FluentValidatorFactor is being asked for ModelValidator and it gets returned. 

What i don't understand is why there are no validator errors for other properties when one of the form fields is blank.

Comment: Can you share the Action code so that we can see what it's doing?

Comment: Done. Updated my post.

Comment: My *guess* would be that the validating code that is generated from the rules works in two phases, such that when there is an error in the first phase, the second phase does not start, and that empty string values for fields of type int are checked in the first phase, whereas things like ranges and so on are checked in a second phase. It sounds reasonable to separate syntactic errors (first phase) from semantic errors (second phase). But again, it's just a guess.

Comment: Ok, I think we're nearly there, but I'm still confused about which scenarios are failing.  Can you outline exactly what the values are for the view model and the error messages that _are_ being generated and compare that to what you _expect_ to be generated.  At the moment it's really confusing and unclear :(

Comment: Ok Let's do it :)

Scenario 1: Form is filled with correct values (by correct i mean bindable to a property in model) but not valid in terms of validation logic.

Result: Validation performs correctly and generates errors for all invalid properties.

Scenario 2: Form field is blank and it will be bound to property A in model. Rest of fields have correct values in terms of type (bindable) but not valid in terms of validator rules.

Comment: Result:

Case 1): If NotEmpty().WithMessage("x") validator isn't used in Rule for property A:

The only error returned in model is about property A. It contains message "'A' must not be empty". All other fields have no errors despite their incorrectness in terms of validation logic.

Comment: Result Case 2) If NotEmpty().WithMessage("x") validator is used in Rule for property A:

The only error returned in model is about property A. It contains message x. All other fields have no errors despite their incorrectness in terms of validation logic.

Comment: I've added an example to the question, can you edit it for the examples that aren't exhibiting the correct behaviour, then I'll be able to work out why it could be.  We need the actual values that are being posted.

Comment: Edit done - now it should be clear what i am asking about. @KrisVandermotten talk about phases may be right but what such a feature isn't documented.